# How can I integrate Google Documents List Data API with coldfusion page?

Tags: coldfusion, google-api, google-docs

Can someone please tell me the step that I should take to integrate google docs in .cfm page. It is a multi-user web application with single log-in , one username n password.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this free library at: http://cfgoogle.riaforge.org/ , read this post: http://www.coldfusionjedi.com/index.cfm/2007/12/8/Google-Docs-CFC

If you want to do it yourself without using the library above, you will need to learn how to consume RESTful services using the `<cfhttp>` tag, and construct and parse XML using `<cfxml>` and `xmlParse()`.

This Yahoo guide introduces how to use CF to consume Yahoo's RESTful services: http://developer.yahoo.com/coldfusion/index.html